# Does linking to any Amazon item allow SE to get affiliate credit?

Tags: discussion

I added a link in a comment to a weed cutter on Amazon on [this question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1027/how-often-should-you-mow-a-growing-lawn). I assumed that the link would be converted to allow SE to get credit for a potential sale as it does on Stack Overlow but that appears not to be the case.

Does the linking mechanism only work with books? Or does it only work on SO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per Jeff's comment below, Amazon links in posts are rewritten, but those in comments are not.

For those who want a little background:

- [Auto-Inserting Stack Overflow affiliate into all Amazon book link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links) (MSO)
- [Summary of Amazon Remnant Ad Experiment](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/summary-of-amazon-remnant-ad-experiment/) (SE Blog)

Comment: comments are rendered in real time, that is, every time they are loaded -- we don't rewrite amazon URLs in comments. Everywhere else we do.